# How to unit test a Joomla 2.5 component

Tags: php, unit-testing, joomla, joomla2.5

Can someone provide an example of how to unit test a Joomla 2.5 component? I'm working through [this joomla mvc component example](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Introduction), which doesn't include unit tests, and I can't find a full example anywhere. My main questions are:

- Where to put component test code
- How to run component unit tests
- Is my test code correct

The Joomla documentation seems incomplete and fragmented - I've read what I can find on unit testing (can't post links due to low rep), which seem to be about testing Joomla itself rather than extensions. The closest I've found is [this](http://www.aldoapp.com/tutorials/10-how-to-do-test-driven-develoment-for-joomla-components.html), which I've based my dummy test on.

### What I've done so far

Component directory structure:

- helloworld/

  - admin/

    - ...
    - tests/

      - bootstrap.php
      - phpunit.xml
      - modelHelloWorldsTest.php
  - site/

    - ...
  - helloworld.xml

To run the tests, I install/copy the component to my Joomla installation. I then run the following command from ~joomla/administration/components/com_helloworld/tests:

```
php phpunit-4.2.phar --bootstrap bootstrap.php .
```

from which I receive

```
Fatal error: Class 'ContentController' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ws_cairnstest\administrator\components\com_helloworld\tests\modelsHelloWorldsTest.php on line 5
```

bootstrap.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('BASEPATH',realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../'));
define('JOOMLA_PATH',realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../../'));
define('JOOMLA_ADMIN_PATH',realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../'));
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'localhost';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET';

if (file_exists(JOOMLA_ADMIN_PATH . '/defines.php'))
{
    include_once JOOMLA_ADMIN_PATH . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', JOOMLA_ADMIN_PATH);
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/helper.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/toolbar.php';
define('JPATH_COMPONENT',JOOMLA_ADMIN_PATH.'/components/com_content');
$app = JFactory::getApplication('administrator');
include BASEPATH.'/controller.php';
```

modelsHelloWorldsTest.php:

```
<?php
class HelloWorldsTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testList(){
        $c = new ContentController();
        $model = $c->getModel('helloworlds');
        $worlds = $model->getItems();
        var_dump($worlds);
        $this->assertNotEmpty($worlds);
    }
}
```

phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    syntaxCheck="false"
    verbose="true">
</phpunit>
```

Comment: This question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Done ([link](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/how-to-unit-test-a-joomla-2-5-component)).

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests for Joomla are typically written to use the PHP Unit framework

To answer your questions 
*Where to put component test code:* at the top level of your repo as follows

Component repo directory structure:

- src

  - admin/
  - site/
- tests

*How to run component unit tests:* test execution follows this pattern

`vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml`

additional details can be found in the php unit documentation https://phpunit.de/documentation.html

*Is your test code correct:* no

You failed to mock your class and methods with the `getMockBuilder()` for testing.

Here are some examples to look at

- https://github.com/joomla-framework/database
- https://github.com/joomla-extensions/weblinks